# Eric Lippert and Neal Gafter C# Puzzle

Tags: c#

This puzzle was presented at NDC 2010. There are links to video from there, but they are all broken. I don't understand the behavior of this program; why does it hang?

```
class Woot
{
    private static float PI;
    private static bool initialized = doInitialize();

    private static bool doInitialize()
    {
        if (!initialized)
        {
            var thread = new Thread(() => { PI = 3.14f; });
            thread.Start();
            thread.Join(); // here
        }
        return true;
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(PI);
    }
}
```

> What is the output of this program? Is it:
>
> - 3.14
> - 0
> - Throws exception
> - None of the above

Comment: @Sayse, you mean metadata Type object hasn't been constructed yet when thread tries to use it? That is my guess.

Comment: @Yola - you might want to put "*And i can't understand behavior of the program. It hangs.*" at the **end** of your question to not give the game away. :)

Comment: @poke That's a totally different question there. Even if the author of the other question meant to ask the same question - this question is more clear.

Comment: @Sebastian The *answer* there explains this question though.

Comment: @poke: No - it does not - it contains the same example but then *asks* the same question without providing the answer to this question.

Comment: I explain what's going on in this blog post: http://ericlippert.com/2013/01/31/the-no-lock-deadlock/. This puzzle, incidentally, was adapted from a very similar puzzle in Neal's book about Java puzzlers; Java has the same behavior when running static initialization.

Comment: I think this is the same as a question I had previously: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27612772/task-run-in-static-initializer

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I believe that problem is caused by static field initalizator.
I've spotted that new thread is started only when `doInitialize` is done (despite `thread.Start()` is called) - **so I suppose that CLR blocks other threads to avoid concurrent access / double field initalization**.

*To sum up*: Newly-created thread is not started by CLR to avoid concurrent access, but main initalization thread waits for child thread to be done what means **deadlock**.

**Edit**

@Sebastian proposed (in a comment) the link that may prove my theory: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/05/03/10159682.aspx

Comment: Very good, likely to be right answer, need some proof links.

Comment: I think these are the relevant links: [Blog1](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/05/03/10159682.aspx) - [Blog2](http://blog.duncanworthy.me/swdev/csdotnet/constructor-gotchas-part3-deadlock/) and finally [ECMAScript](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-335.pdf#page=178&zoom=auto,87,610")

Comment: @Yola yes, I'm digging into MSDN to find a prove. The only thing I've found so far is statement, that static field initialization is thread safe, but no statement how thread-safety is ensured.

Comment: Eric Lippert has a blog entry that details exactly that problem, [The no-lock deadlock](http://ericlippert.com/2013/01/31/the-no-lock-deadlock/)

Answer (score 16):

`doInitialize` is executed when the static type is constructed and then halts until the thread that sets `PI` terminates.

The thread that tries to set `PI` however cannot run until the type is initialized, which only happens once the initialization (static constructor and static initializers) are finished—which didn’t happen yet as per above.

So the program deadlocks.

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9792163/race-condition-with-static-class/9792537#9792537) by Eric Lippert.

Comment: This is highly misleading.  If static members could not be set until the type initializer completed, then the type initializer could not set static member variables -- clearly false.  The fact that `PI` won't be set until after the static constructor completes is an effect of the peculiar arrangement of code in this particular program, by no means a universal statement.  It would have been better to say "The code that sets `PI` cannot run..."

Answer (score 4):

Thread will never finish, so thread.Join()  will never return.
doInitialize() is executed from static constructor.
In static constructor we are trying to set the static property, but we can't access the static property unless static constructor is finished.
 race